# Rxjs: merge observables with intermediate subscribe and complete, and an overall complete

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, rxjs, observable

I am looking a the right operators to perform the following:

I have multiple form fields, each of them having an array of observables to perform some validations. On change, I merge these observables to perform:

- catch error: stopping the validations and setting a field error
- complete: all observables successed meaning the field is valid

My code looks like this:

```js
arrayObs.map(({ fieldName, obs }) => Observable.merge.apply(this, obs)
  .subscribe(
    (result) => {
      // Nothing to do here
    },
    ({ message }) => {
      this.props.handleError(fieldName, message) // add error
    },
    () => {
      this.props.resetError() // reset error on complete
    }
  ), this)
```

On submit though, I would like the perform the same treatment but on each fields at the same time and perform an overall `onComplete` if all arrays of observables completed successfuly to trigger the post.

What would my code look this? Am I looking for something like `forkJoin` to run all arrays of observables at the same time but wait for all arrays to finish before running some more code?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging and a lot of tweaking in JSFiddle, I came up with the idea of creating an array of custom observables using the `create` operator (one per field).

This way, I am free to emit a value whenever the `merge` completes meaning the field's validations are finished and successful. I then subscribe to these events using the `forkJoin` operator, that emits only when all observables completed successfully.

You can have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mentinet/540011q1/

I added two examples of scenarios: one with 2 valid fields, and one with a third field that have a validation that fails. I also changed the `merge` operator to `concat` so that the validations are performed in the given order.

What do you guys think of that solution? Do you have any better idea or advise to make it cleaner or more performant?